# How to transform Parameter Pack into something else than std::tuple?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

It is better explained by an example:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct OnePair
{
    using TupleOfArgs = std::tuple<T1, T2>;
    using TupleOfPairs = std::tuple<std::pair<T1, T2>>;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
struct TwoPairs
{
    using TupleOfArgs = std::tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>;
    using TupleOfPairs = std::tuple<std::pair<T1, T2>, std::pair<T3, T4>>;
};

template <typename... Args>
struct NPairs
{
    using TupleOfArgs = std::tuple<Args...>;
//  using TupleOfPairs = ???
};
```

OnePair defines a tuple with one pair.
TwoPairs defines a tuple with two pairs.

How do I define TupleOfPairs in NPairs so it transforms the Parameter Pack to std::tuple of pairs?

Is it possible to achieve that with the std library? Maybe with boost::mpl?

Two answers, both great.
@chris uses an iterative method while @aschepler uses a recursive solution.
Personally, I found the recursive solution easier to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one straightforward way with a recursive helper:

```
template <typename PairsTuple, typename... Ts>
struct ZipPairs;

template <typename PairsTuple>
struct ZipPairs<PairsTuple> { using type = PairsTuple; };

template <typename... Pairs, typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
struct ZipPairs<std::tuple<Pairs...>, T1, T2, Ts...>
{
    using type = typename ZipPairs<
        std::tuple<Pairs..., std::pair<T1, T2>>, Ts...>::type;
};

template <class... Args>
struct NPairs
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) % 2 == 0);
    using TupleOfArgs = std::tuple<Args...>;
    using TupleOfPairs = typename ZipPairs<std::tuple<>, Args...>::type;
};
```

Comment: Nice solution. I tried to replace std::tuple with boost::mpl::list and for some reason, it doesn't work. I get the following error: `error: wrong number of template arguments (21, should be at least 0)`. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: I think you're not supposed to manipulate MPL template arguments directly like this does with tuples, but instead use metafunctions like `boost::mpl::insert` and `boost::mpl::push_back`. (Looks like `mpl::list` isn't really variadic, but has a bunch of dummy default arguments, probably because it was originally C++03 / for C++03 compatibility.) And `mpl::list` doesn't support `push_back`. There would be ways to get `mpl::list` working, but an `mpl::vector` would be the more direct translation: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed600f95e53df5e0

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. Your example was very helpful. Sorry for not replying sooner, it took me some time to return to that problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the familiar index sequence trick, but with half the size ([live example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/n4M9u9)):

```
static constexpr auto get_tuple() {
    constexpr auto N = sizeof...(Args);
    static_assert(N%2 == 0);

    using ArgsTuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
    auto impl = []<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::tuple<
            // Is goes from 0 to N/2, representing Ith pair
            std::pair<std::tuple_element_t<Is*2, ArgsTuple>, std::tuple_element_t<Is*2 + 1, ArgsTuple>>...
        >{};
    };

    return impl(std::make_index_sequence<N/2>{});
}

using TupleOfArgs = decltype(get_tuple());
```

If you don't have C++20, you'll have to expand the lambda out to a function instead of being able to use the nice inline index sequence expansion, but the core still functions. It might also be a bit cleaner with a typelist instead of `std::tuple`, but it's workable.

Comment: Nice solution. As a side notice, I couldn't make it work on vs2017.

Comment: @Gils, The C++20 templated lambda definitely wouldn't. I don't remember when the metaprogramming support really ramped up in VS, but the rest of it might work with the lambda separated out to a different function.

Comment: Of course, it wouldn't. But I took your advice and tried to take out the lambda out to a function. I got `'NPairs<Args...>::get_tuple': a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined` error. I didn't spend too much time on it. The recursive solution was easer for me to use as I'm using C++11. Thanks a lot for the answer though. I really liked it.

Comment: @Gils, Ah, this snippet relies on the C++14 return type deduction. You could, of course, refactor it into something C++11-compliant, but the recursive approach would probably be much more readable.